# Handle exception from load balancer only once (when failover is exhausted)

Tags: apache-camel

My code consumes jms queue and through lb redirects to external http client.
I need to log original message for every failed delivery to local directory. 
Problem is that onException is caught by each failover. 
Is there any way how to achieve this?

Pseudo code:

```
onException(Exception.class).useOriginalMessage()
    .setHeader(...)
    .to("file...")
    .setHeader(...)
    .to("file...")

from("activemq...")
    .process(...)
    .loadBalance().failover(...)
        .to("lb-route1")
        .to("lb-route2")
    .end()
    .process()
    .to("file...")

from("lb-route1")
    .recipientList("dynamic url")
.end()

from("lb-route2")
    .recipientList("dynamic url")
.end()
```

Comment: You can use the CircuitBreaker Component along with errorHandler to do this and limit the retries to 1

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this logic with multiple to statements, but when I have my list of endpoints in an array this logic functions just fine.  I will attempt to deliver to the first endpoint, if I cannot I will attempt to deliver this to the second endpoint.  If an exception occurs at the second endpoint it will propagate back to the route's error handler.  If you need it to round robin instead, change the last false on the failover statement to a true.

```
String[] endpointList = {"direct:end1", "direct:end2"};

from("direct:start")
    .loadbalance().failover(endpointList.length-1, false, false)
    .to(endpointList);
```